# SASS template strings. Is it a way to use them?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, less

Maybe it's a trivial question, but I have not found any info about `sass` template strings, as in `less` syntax it has:

`less`: `@media-screen-phone: ~'screen and (max-width: 540px)';`

with the next usage:

```
// ...some *.less file

@media-screen-phone: {
  // ... some style rules
}

// ...
```

So, is it a way to use such approach from `less` in `sass` like I shown above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LessCss tilde (`~`) 'function' is only a helper:

> Notice that our CSS property value is quoted, which we don't want.
>
> This is where the tilde comes into play. If you precede the quoted value with a tilde, the tokens will still be grouped into a single value, but the quotes will be stripped off.
>
> That is all that the tilde does - strip quotes. *It does nothing else*. If you use tildes currently, you probably don't actually need them in half the cases. If you're anything like me, you [incorrectly] copy-pasted them from online demos without actually knowing what it was doing.

Citation from [Thinking About Strings, Quotes, Tokens, And Tildes In Less CSS](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2645-thinking-about-strings-quotes-tokens-and-tildes-in-less-css.htm)
. Emphasis like in original.

The buzzword for SCSS is [*string interpolation*](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)

It does the same, but not at the time of definition, but at the time of usage.

```
// SCSS
$media-screen-phone: "screen and (max-width: 540px)";

@media #{$media-screen-phone} {
  body {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this approach, but it's not the same as in `.less`. Any idea of how to use it without side-add rules?

Comment: This SCCS code might make it clearer `$media-screen-phone: "screen and (max-width: 540px)";body { &:before {  content: #{$media-screen-phone}; content: $media-screen-phone; content: "#{$media-screen-phone}";}}`